# How to do killOp in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://test:test@127.0.0.1:27017/admin")
myclient.admin.command(killOp(1234)) ??
```

I can not find the right grammar。

Answer (score 0):

could use this:

```
infos = myclient.admin.command('currentOp')['inprog']
for i in infos:
    myclient.admin.command({ "killOp": 1, "op": i["opid"] })
```